# Add props to React render call with looping construct

Tags: reactjs

Say I have an array ("props") that I want to render a React component with. Something like:

```
const props = [];

ReactDOM.render(<Comp prop0={props[0]} prop1={props[1]/>, document.getElementById('foo'));
```

Is there acceptable way to add props to a React component using some loop construct instead of "hardcoding" it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, you would use the spread operator there:

```
var props = {};
props.foo = 'something';
props.bar = 'something else';

ReactDOM.render(<Component {...props} />, someDomElement);
```

Comment: Exactly. May add this link for reference: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html

Comment: thanks for this answer! Do you know how to do the same thing, but have multiple children as well as multiple props?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you wanted to both render a variable number of children with a variable number of props, you could do it like so:

```
const React = require('react');


module.exports =  function(children){

    return React.createClass({

        renderChildren: function(){

            return children.map(function(Child){

                  return (
                      <div>
                          <Child {...Child.propz}/>
                      </div>
                  )
            });

        },

        render: function(){

            return (

                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
                    <title>Title</title>
                </head>
                <body>

                <div>
                    {this.renderChildren()}
                </div>

                </body>
                </html>

            )

        }

    });
};
```